# ImportXML in Spreadsheet is Returning Error When Trying to Import Total YouTube Channel Views

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a spreadsheet that pulls data from a YouTube channels "about" page to get the subscribers and views of that channel.

For example, to import the views, I am using:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/c/youtubecreators/about","//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-channel-about-metadata-renderer']")
```

but I am getting the "Imported Content is Empty" error.

I have also tried to inspect the subscriber and view counts and copy/paste in the XPath into the sheet without much luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*")), 
 "where Col1 contains '"&CHAR(10)&"Creators'", ), 
 ".x22text.x22:.x22(.+).x22,.x22bold.x22")
```

[image]